# ng-repeat, after filling a row with divs, how do i make a new row to continue filing?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating divs whose class is "col-lg-3" which is 4 per row.
Bootstrap grids require a "container" div, which contain "row" divs, which are then filled with "col-*-*" divs.
So, how do I create a new "row" div every time a row has 4 divs, and continue to fill the next "row" div?

(I saw  similar questions about tables and lists, but not like this.)

For example, using an array of 6 objects [object1 - object6], this would be the result i would like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">object1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">object2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">object3</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">object4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">object5</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">object6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need to create a new row on every 4 iterations. If your css is correct, every 5th element will start on a new line anyways. Also providing some code would help

Comment: my code involves a lot more details, which may be distracting to the actual question. ($http, json, etc.)

Comment: you could give us a minimum reproducable example on codepen/plunkr or else its very hard to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap 5.0 they have allowed "col-" divs to be used without being nested in "row" divs.
this means you can either do ng-repeat without having to create "row" divs.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#standalone-column-classes

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to chunk the initial array into a multi-dimensional array and use a nested `ng-if`

```js
// create some dummy data of 15 objects
const data = Array.from({length:15},(_,i)=>({text:`Item #${i+1}`}));


angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function() {    
    this.rows = [];
    // chunk into sub arrays of  4 per row
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 4) {
      this.rows.push(data.slice(i, i + 4))
    }
  })
```

```css
.row {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin: .5em
}

.col {
  width: 15%;
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.rows" class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="item in row" class="col">{{item.text}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i  would have a very big array (or am calling a lot of objects) won't it take a lot of time to chunk it into a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Far less involved than using directives in the view. What do you consider a "big array"?

Comment: lets say 40+
the code i am currently working on is a lot more complicated. i isolated the part i was having trouble with.
i didn't want to have to deal with $http and other directives...

Comment: 40 elements in array is considered small in size